# Can player's build be changed in some way?

Tags: dnd-4e

I wonder if there are any legal ways to change a build in DnD-4e? A friend of mine heard somewhere that some parts of build can be changed once per level - is that true and if yes what exactly can be changed?

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are referring to a subsystem called retraining.

Once per level up you can retrain (outside of normal level up retraining rules), one power, feat, theme or skill selection into another of same.

So if I choose a feat at L1 and want to swap it for something else at L2 I can do so, provided that the following are true:

- I qualify for the feat I want to select
- The feat I am retraining is not a prerequisite for something I've already taken. (So you can't retrain an MC entry feat if you have an MC power swap feat).

This is especially common with feats in Paragon and Epic tiers as you can retrain Heroic Tier feats in order to take more than the generally allowed number of Paragon tier feats.

With power retraining, you have to take a power of the level of the power slot or lower. There are two types of power retraining though. The first and most common is the natural progression retrains. As you level up, and enter paragon and epic tier, you reach the cap of the number of daily and encounter powers you are allowed to have. In order to gain higher level powers, you have to retrain lower level ones. You can retrain any of your lower level powers, but you usually choose your lowest level power to retain.

When you retrain at level up (and not as part of normal power selection), you can choose any power you have, though you have to replace it with a power of it's level or lower.

Skills can be retrained for any other skill that you qualify for. Again beware that you cannot retrain our skills that are pre-reqs for other things or that are granted specifically by a class feature with no alternate selections.

Character themes can also be retrained. Again you'll have to retrain out of anything else it is a pre-req for before you can swap it out.

If you want to change *other* parts of your build other than these things, that's a conversation to have with your GM. He may or may not allow it, but that is outside of the codified subsystem of retraining.

Comment: It's worth noting that if you find someone running the LFR rules (Living Forgotten Realms, which was officially organized play but which still remains publicly available), they allow much more extensive retraining.  They're not official rules from Wizards, but they're common enough that you may run into them.